# Llenar inputs dependiendo de otro input

Tags: javascript, input

Les cuento lo siguiente tengo un formulario donde el primer campo se llama NIT, cuando el usuario digita el numero, mediante JS se hace una consulta mysql y si encuentra el registro regresa los resultados y automaticamente rellena los otros dos imputs nombre y direccion.

El codigo que tengo funciona bien, solo que en ves de traerme el dato de nombre al imput nombre, me arrastra al input tanto el nombre como la direccion y asi pasa tambien en el imput de direccion, arrastra el dato del nombre y direccion, como no se ada de JS acudo a ustedes para que me ayuden por favor a verificar donde tengo el error.

dejo los codigos para ver si me pueden ayudar, de antemano gracias.

este es el **form.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript Ajax POST</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <label>RUT:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="nit" name="n_nit"></div>
        <br>
        <label>NOMBRE:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"></div>
        <br>
        <label>direccion:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="dir" name="dir"></div>

    </form>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("nit").onchange = function(){alerta()};
    function alerta() {
        // Creando el objeto para hacer el request
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Objeto PHP que consultaremos
        request.open("POST", "services.php");

        // Definiendo el listener
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // Revision si fue completada la peticion y si fue exitosa
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                // Ingresando la respuesta obtenida del PHP
                document.getElementById("nombre").value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById("dir").value = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        // Recogiendo la data del HTML
        var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var formData = new FormData(myForm);

        // Enviando la data al PHP
        request.send(formData);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

este es el **services.php**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $NIT = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["n_nit"]));

    // Codigo para buscar en tu base de datos acá


    require 'conexion.php';

    $sqlsi = "SELECT * FROM gcs WHERE n_nit = '$NIT'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sqlsi);
    $dato = $resultado->fetch_assoc();


    $nombre = $dato['n_est'];
    echo $nombre;
    $dir = $dato['d_est'];
    echo $dir;


} else {
    echo "<p>No se encontro el nombre en la DB!!</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en que a ambos campos les asignas la respuesta completa:

```
document.getElementById("nombre").value = this.responseText;
document.getElementById("dir").value = this.responseText;
```

Tienes que separar para cada uno el valor que le corresponde.

Si tu respuesta es un json podría corregirse así:

```
document.getElementById("nombre").value = respuestaJson.nombre;
document.getElementById("dir").value = respuestaJson.dir;
```

**Actualización** (observación hecha por @quevedo):

Puedes reemplazar el código:

```
$nombre = $dato['n_est'];
echo $nombre;
$dir = $dato['d_est'];
echo $dir;
```

por:

```
$nombre = $dato['n_est'];
$dir = $dato['d_est'];

echo json_encode([
   'nombre' => $nombre,
   'dir'    => $dir
]);
```

eso debería dar una salida en formato json, compatible con la solución que te propuse.

**Actualización, configurar la petición para recibir respuesta json:**

Agrega el responseType a la configuración de la petición:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = 'json';
```

Y para leer los valores en lugar de `responseText` usa `response`:

```
document.getElementById("nombre").value = this.response.nombre;
document.getElementById("dir").value = this.response.dir;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder tan pronto, trate de implementar lo que tu me sugeriste pero sigue llevando los valores completos al input, alguna otra idea?

Comment: Cuál es el formato de la respuesta? Haz un console.log(this.responseText) para ver que te imprime en consola y agrégalo en la pregunta.

Comment: @CamiloKent estas enviando secuencialmente dos valores que son tomados sin identificadores en el objeto `this.responseText` Debes preparar la salida, antes de enviarla y devolverla con un solo echo, usando un formato que puedas manejar, o enviar una marca separadora intermedia que puedas reconocer al procesar la respuesta.

Comment: hola, gracias por su ayuda, implemente las obervaciones hechas por uds preparando la salida con echo json_encode($dato); y recogiendo los datos con document.getElementById("nombre").value = this.responseText.n_est;
document.getElementById("dir").value = this.responseText.d_est; el problema es que ahora en los inputs no solo trae la info de n_est y d_est sino de toda la tabla completa en este formato: {"gcs_id":"1",, alguna idea?

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta. Ahora en lugar de `this.responseText.n_est` usa `this.responseText.nombre`, lo mismo para `d_est` cambialo por `dir`

Comment: Antes de hacer json_encode agrupa en un array $salida = [dato1 => valor1, dato2=>valor2]; los valores que necesitas con sus claves y luego haces json_encode($salida)

Comment: Actualizo: implemente el array $salida = [dato1 => valor1, dato2=>valor2]; y luego imprimi el echo json_encode($salida) , pero aun y con eso en los inputs sigue mostrando lo siguiente: {"nombre":"nombre desde la bd","dir":"direccion desde la bd"}, lo que veo es q por mas q se hagan cambios en ambos inputs muestra la misma informacion

Comment: Estás leyendo los datos de la respuesta de esta forma: `this.responseText.nombre;`  Y  `this.responseText.dir;`

Comment: Asi es, los datos se esta leyendo de esta manera this.responseText.nombre y this.responseText.dir

Comment: Puede ser porque la solicitud ajax no está configurada para recibir json. Actualicé la respuesta y agregué una conversión a json antes de leer los valores

Comment: Funciona perfecto, el tema esta en que si lo pruebo desde xampp o wamp server me da el error que les he venido mencionando, pero si lo subo al hosting funciona como esperaba, en todo caso deje una prueba de como funciona en el siguiente vinculo https://pruebasdcpb.000webhostapp.com/ , alguna idea de porque en el wamp no se ejecuta bien?

Answer (score 1):

gracias a la ayuda de @crrlos y de @quevedo logre solucionar el tema, dejo el codigo completo por si lo requiere alguien mas..

formulario.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript Ajax POST</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <label>RUT:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="nit" name="n_nit"></div>
        <br>
        <label>NOMBRE:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"></div>
        <br>
        <label>direccion:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="dir" name="dir"></div>

    </form>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("nit").onchange = function(){alerta()};
    function alerta() {
        // Creando el objeto para hacer el request
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.responseType = 'json';

        // Objeto PHP que consultaremos
        request.open("POST", "services.php");

        // Definiendo el listener
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // Revision si fue completada la peticion y si fue exitosa
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                // Ingresando la respuesta obtenida del PHP
                document.getElementById("nombre").value = this.response.nombre;
                document.getElementById("dir").value = this.response.dir;
            }
        };

        // Recogiendo la data del HTML
        var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var formData = new FormData(myForm);

        // Enviando la data al PHP
        request.send(formData);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

services.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $NIT = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["n_nit"]));

    // Codigo para buscar en tu base de datos acá


    require 'conexion.php';

    $sqlsi = "SELECT * FROM gcs WHERE n_nit = '$NIT'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sqlsi);
    $dato = $resultado->fetch_assoc();



$nombre = $dato['n_est'];
$dir = $dato['d_est'];

echo json_encode([
   'nombre' => $nombre,
   'dir'    => $dir
]);





} else {
    echo "<p>No se encontro el nombre en la DB!!</p>";
}
?>
```

Y por si lo quieren ver en funcionamiento esta dispuesto en este hosting temporal https://pruebasdcpb.000webhostapp.com/

Gracias Amigos de la comunidad Stack overflow